# how to pass a callback function as constructor parameter and assign to class property

Tags: php

I'm trying to do something like this:

First, I create the identity class

```
class Identity {
    private $identity;

    public function __construct($identiy) {
        $this->identity = $identiy;
    }

    public function getIdentity($value) {
        return $this->identity($value);
    }
}
```

Then I create an instance of the class:

```
$identity = new Identity(function ($value){
    return "1";
});
echo $identity->identity(1);
```

In JavaScript, I can do something like that but I don't know how to do it in PHP. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. Your property is private, so you need to use the getter to access it.
2. There is no `identity` method which will cause php to error out. Using a temporary variable solves that.

   ```
   class Identity {
       private $identity;

       public function __construct($identiy) {
           $this->identity = $identiy;
       }

       public function getIdentity($value) {
           // Use a temporary variable for your function
           $func = $this->identity;
           return $func($value);
       }
   }


   $identity = new Identity(function ($value){
       return "1";
   });
   // Access the getter instead of the property
   echo $identity->getIdentity(1);
   ```

[An example.](https://3v4l.org/clKtL)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for [what](https://www.codepunker.com/blog/basic-usage-of-closures-in-php) you need:

```
    $var = function() {
      return 'I am a ' . func_get_arg(0);
    };
    print_r($var('Closure'));
```